# Display single attribute value from SQL using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I have reused my code for pagination to create a product details page which (only for demo) tries to reach attribute `bookPrice` inside of the `book` table which has another PK attribute `bookID` with value of 2. To say shortly: display the price of the book which has bookID=2.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"  %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>

   <% 
   ResultSet rsDetail = null;
   PreparedStatement psDetail=null;
   Connection conn = null;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book_store","root", "daters");
    String sqlDetail="SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookID=2";
    psDetail=conn.prepareStatement(sqlDetail);
    rsDetail=psDetail.executeQuery();
    %>

<h2> <%=rsDetail.getString("bookPrice")%> </h2>
```

compiler says that the error happens in line of `<h2>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `rsDetail.next()` before you can access the data.

```
psDetail=conn.prepareStatement(sqlDetail);
rsDetail=psDetail.executeQuery();
if(rsDetail.next()){ // moves to first row
%>

 <h2> <%=rsDetail.getString("bookPrice")%> </h2>

 <% } %>
```

Comment: I was thinking about that but din't know how to manage. Thank you.

Comment: if(rsDetail.next()) EDIT